# Difference between #take_while and #select

Tags: ruby

What is the difference between `#take_while` and `#select`

Don't both methods do the same thing?

```
p [1,2,3,4].take_while { |e| e < 3 } # prints [1,2]
p [1,2,3,4].select     { |e| e < 3 } # prints [1,2]
```

Answer (score 5):

There is a difference, take_while stops from the moment the evaluation in the block is false, select will continue and evaluate everything.

```
[1,2,3,4,1].take_while{ |e| e < 3 } # prints [1,2]
[1,2,3,4,1].select{ |e| e < 3 } # prints [1,2,1]
```

Answer (score 3):

**take_while** returns an array of all prior elements until the block returns nil or false.

**select** returns an array containing those elements for which the block returns a true value. so for example if you have [1,2,3,4,1] **select** would return [1,2,1]

```
p [1,2,3,4,1].select     { |e| e < 3 } # prints [1,2,1]
```

Where as **take_while** would return [1,2]

`p [1,2,3,4,1].take_while { |e| e < 3 } # prints [1,2]`